# Which is the best way to Create object Repository in Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

As per my study I know two ways
1. Create page class; keep all objects in that class & access using object of that class (POM)
2. Create Properties file 
Which is best way in between them or any other standard way to create object repository in selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Refer POM Model (Page object model) :-

```
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/
```

Comment: I strongly recommend the Page Object Model. Properly implemented it is a great way to organize your code, reduce maintenance efforts, and reduce script creation time.

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach is to to create 1 single GUI.properties file, to document all the object properties.

```
pageHome.textboxUsernameXPath = ""
pageHome.textboxPasswordXPath = ""
pageHome.buttonSignInXPath = ""
```

A lot of tools are endorsing that approach: TestComplete, TestArchitect, Katalon, ...